# Adding a time stamp to copied column

Tags: google-apps-script, timestamp

I am using this script to copy a column from one report and record it in a historical log:

```
function copyDailyreport() {

var sheetFrom = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("MSM");

var sheetTo = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("MSM Daily Totals");

var valuesToCopy = sheetFrom.getRange(4, 11, sheetFrom.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();

sheetTo.getRange(1,sheetTo.getLastColumn()+1,valuesToCopy.length,1).setValues(valuesToCopy);
}
```

The code is working great and does what I want, but I would like to add a time stamp to the column either above or below the copied information.

I've tried a couple different things and have not been successful. I imagine it's something simple and I've over complicated it.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: above/below the row or before/after the column?

Comment: above or below would be best. Right now the column copies into the new sheet next to the previous column.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the appendRow method to add a new row after the copy operation is complete.

```
sheetTo.appendRow([new Date()]);
```

Comment: The code adds the date, but to a new row below, but not under the new data entered in the column.

Answer (score 0):

This will work with unshift method which will append the timestamp at the start of the column

```
function copyDailyreport() {

var timeStamp=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MM/dd/yyyy");

var now= new Date(), 
h= now.getHours(), 
m= now.getMinutes(), 
s= now.getSeconds(),
timeStamp=timeStamp+" "+h+":"+m+":"+s ;

var sheetFrom = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("MSM");

var sheetTo = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("MSM Daily Totals");

var valuesToCopy = sheetFrom.getRange(4, 11, sheetFrom.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();

valuesToCopy.unshift([timeStamp]);

sheetTo.getRange(1,sheetTo.getLastColumn()+1,valuesToCopy.length,1).setValues(valuesToCopy);
}
```

Hope this could help!.